# ArrayCollection sort by czech locale

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sorting

how can i sort String field in ArrayCollection by czech locale... a á b c č d ď e é ě f g h ch i í .....

alike as Collator("cs-CZ", CollatorMode.MATCHING); for Array

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may helps you, [Adobe Globalization](http://blogs.adobe.com/globalization/) blog also show sorting example in data grid

Hope that helps